# SQL to get, inserting new entry if absent

Tags: java, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm not sure if this question is properly in the domain of SQL, MySQL, stored routines or even JDBC.  Basically I want a SQL function that looks like:

```
INSERT IGNORE (id, data) INTO table
SELECT id FROM table WHERE `data` = data
```

This needs to be initiated from Java via raw SQL or a stored routine.  This looks incredibly poor because if the `insert ignore` succeeds, it shouldn't have to follow right up with a SQL query to get what it just inserted.  Note that `id` will be autogenerated. Best way to do this that's efficient on the # of SQL queries and readable and such?  I don't really have any idea how efficient an INSERT IGNORE is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), with a little bit of logic:

```
INSERT IGNORE ... INTO Table
SELECT IF(LAST_INSERT_ID() <> 0, LAST_INSERT_ID(), (SELECT id FROM table WHERE `data` = data))
```

(untested)